# How to replace comma separated values to comma separated ids in the same/individual cell in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table where Products are mapped with ingredients and another table where Ingredients are mapped with IDs like this below :

[image]

Below is what I need :

[image]

Here I want to replace the comma separated ingredients values in "Data Table" with their IDs from "Master Table".

I checked out Replace Function to accomplish this task but couldn't manage to do it somehow.

=REPLACE(C2,1,LEN(C2),..

Here C2 i.e. Ingredient column in "Data Table" doesn't have single value to replace it easily, they are available in combination for which replace statement is not the correct solution although the same can be handled programmatically but I want to do it in excel way.

It would be very grateful if someone can guide me with solution to this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To be very honest, I am new to excel considering such logic, I can do this by some javascript and C# program but I want to it through excel. I tried writing replace statement which needed some more additions.

Comment: My guess is that it **will** be best to solve via VBA so the [excel-vba] tag was probably appropriate (but there are some pretty clever people watching the [excel-formulas] tag who will possibly come up with a formula solution!), but questions are always better received if you at least show you have attempted to make a **start** on the solution.

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you run into problems. For formulas, you will need to have multiple nesting levels or split your data using helper columns.  VBA would be simplest. Please read the HELP pages for information as to [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

This is not a direct solution nor a VBA solution but through a manual action and 2 simple formula's, this is possible.

I used a combination of `Data>Text to Columns`, `VLOOKUP` and `Concatenate` functions to achieve your result table.

Step 1.: Delimit your data using `Text To Column`.

Step 2.: Add `VLOOKUP` Functions for each ingredients.

Step 3. Use the `Concatenate` function to bring all the `VLOOKUPS` together.

You can find my solution using your example [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-LViKO6psQYTLyJlwRxX5Q0_4OysS4obS7opISRAx04/edit?usp=sharing) in a Google sheet:

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can come up with is a nested `SUBSTITUTE` function like this one:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(C1,D1,E1),D2,E2),D3,E3),D4,E4)
```

Here your Ingredients are in Column D and their respective IDs in Column E (i.e. your Master table in Sheet 2).

As you probably have many ingredients, you can use `CONCATENATE` to create the correct formula. Assuming your have your recipe in `column E`, your ingredients in `column F` and the corresponding ingredient IDs in `column G`:

- Write `SUBSTITUTE(E2,F2,G2)` into `D1` (where `E2`, corresponds to the first entry in the Ingredients column in your data table, `F2` corresponds to your first ingredient in your Master table, and `G2` corresponds to the related first Ingredient ID in the Master table)
- Write `SUBSTITUTE`into `A2`
- Write `=ADDRESS(ROW(F3),COLUMN(F3),4)` into `B2` (where `F3` references your second ingredient in your Master table)
- Write `=ADDRESS(ROW(G3),COLUMN(G3),4)` into `C2` (where `G3` references the corresponding ID to the second ingredient in your Master table)
- Write `=CONCATENATE(A2,"(",D1,",",B2,",",C2,")")` into `D2`
- Drag A2:D2 down as far as necessary

You now have the necessary formula. Copy, paste the last entry, selecting `Paste Values` and set a `=` in front.

[image]